# find the max value of each column with spatial range of row in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to code my Sliding Window and I have a huge data shep like this
feature x
[a  b  c  d  g
1  2  3  4  5  6
2  4  5  6  9  4

3  6  7  8  6  0
4  2  3  5  7  9
5  2  2  2  2  2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9AbI.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxEdS.png)
and
label y
[0
1
1
2
0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IjNU.png)
I want to define df with the same columns and zipping every 3 rows in one with the max value of each column --> this for feature x
and define df2 with the same column and zipping every 3 rows in one with the most frequent.

there someone can help me :(

the first row maybe like this
6  7  8  9  6 with label 1

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer but you can improve it!
[image: the code of the dataFarme]